# Jquery Facebox - Login problem

Tags: jquery, authentication, facebox

I'm going to implant Jquery plugin [Facebox](http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/) to show popup box with username and password input fields to login in my site. The problem is that browsers like Firefox won't show remembered password in password field.

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's linked to your firefox settings and not to the jquery plugin

Comment: I tried to unhide Facebox div, but in this case saved login informations are shown.

Comment: It's strange, i have the same implementation with a simplemodal plugin and it works.

Comment: Do you load Facebox from external url or hidden div?

Comment: from a partialview, i'm using asp.net mvc.

Comment: Thx for the info, I'll try this on blank page to see if there is any bug in my code.

Comment: Nope, I tried on "blank" page with Firefox and IE and it's the same... Inputs username and password are saved, but won't show if the form is shown with Facebox popup.